# How to deal with "distorted" array-output

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to build a "connect four" in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell), usable via console commands, without any GUI.

I've written the code to initialize the gamefield via the output of an array.  However, after the *newline* element in the array, after the very first line, the output gets moved a little to the left:

[image: image of console output]

The code i'm using that produces the error:

```
$initializegamefield = @()
$savedgamefield = @()

for ($i = 0; $i -lt 48; $i++) {
    if (($i -eq 7 ) -or ($i -eq 15) -or ($i -eq 23) -or ($i -eq 31) -or ($i -eq 39) -or ($i -eq 47)) {
        $initializegamefield += "`n"
        Write-Host "$($initializegamefield)"
        $savedgamefield += $initializegamefield
        $initializegamefield = @()
    } else {
        $initializegamefield += "A"
    }
}
#Write-Host "$($initializegamefield)"
Write-Host "$($savedgamefield)"
```

Here I've basically initialized the gamefield two times for testing purposes.
The first time it is initialized, it is done via outputting the array `$initializegamefield` after it has been filled with **ONE ROW** including the newline element.

Afterwards `$initializegamefield` is emptied (see if structure).
In addition, before it is emptied, it is saved to `$savedgamefield`.

Whilst the formatting of the gamefield is okay with the way I do it with `$initializegamefield` it isn't okay anymore when doing it it with `$savedgamefield`.

How can I avoid having this distortion of `$savedgamefield`?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to tell me ^^
Do you mean that I shall cut out 

 $initializegamefield += "n"`

???
But in this case, there won't be any newline.
I will just get a full horizontal output.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused and the comment was incorrect (and I removed it), please refer to the answer from [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers).

Answer (score 1):

Since your game field is a 6x8 array I'd recommend actually initializing it as an 6x8 array:

```
$height = 6
$width  = 8

$gamefield = New-Object 'Object[,]' $height, $width
for ($i=0; $i -lt $height; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j -lt $width; $j++) {
        $gamefield[$i, $j] = 'A'
    }
}
```

or at least as a "jagged" array (an array of arrays):

```
$height = 6
$width  = 8

$gamefield = @()
for ($i=0; $i -lt $height; $i++) {
    $gamefield += ,@(1..$width | ForEach-Object { 'A' })
}
```